# How to use Spring MVC resources static images in tapestry

Tags: spring-mvc, tapestry

I am developing an application using Tapestry 5.3.1

I have tried to use MVC resources mapping to cache images, But it doesn't works!

Here my coding:

Context xml configuration:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="file:${catalina.home}/props/" cache-period="1234" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Index.tml:

```
<img src="/images/home.jpg"  width="130" />
```

I have this home.jpg file in tomcat catalina home path props folder.

Application runs successfully, however the images are not loaded!!

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your best bet is the following:

```
<img src="${context:images/home.jpg}"/>
```

This is a standard <img> tag that has a *dynamic* attribute.

"context:" is a binding prefix; it decides how the remainder of the string in interpreted. Here, a path to a file underneath the context root.

What you'll see in the browser for the `src` attribute will vary depending on the version of Tapestry; it will be a URL that is routed through Tapestry and gets a far-future expires header (5.3) and an ETag (5.4). The URL will include a application-wide version number (5.3) or a checksum based on the file content (5.4).

Also, there are hooks in Tapestry to convert the URL into a reference to a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

In other words, we're telling the browser that it should cache the value and not ask for it again. That's very important for scalability and performance.

I don't know what the mvc:/Spring stuff is supposed to do, but it will likely not be as functional as Tapestry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/home.jpg"  width="130" />
```

Comment: I get the contextpath using Tapestry & attached before images but it also not works!